# Ошибка «Call to a member function count() on array» при использовании ActiveRecord в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

**Контроллер:**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $category = Category::getCategoryimg();

    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $category->count(), 'pageSize' => 1]);
    $models = $category->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();
    return $this->render('index',
        [
        'category'=> $category,
        'models' => $models,
        'pages' => $pages,

    ]);
}
```

**Модель:**

```
public static function getCategoryimg()
{
    $data = Category::find()
        ->from('category')
        ->where(['parent_id' => null])
        ->all();
    return $data;
}
```

**Ошибка:**

> Call to a member function count() on array

**Вопрос:**

Почему `count()` так реагирует на `all()`?

---

**Представление:**

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

?>

<div class="content-index">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($category as $cat): ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/category/album?id=<?= $cat->id?>">
            <img src="<?= '/backend/web/'.$cat->category_image ?>" alt="image" width="500" height="500"  class="img-rounded">
          </a>
          <h4 align="center"><?= $cat->name?></h4>
          <?php  if(!($cat->parent_id == null)) { ?>
            <h5 align="center">Category: <?= $cat->category->name ?></h5>
            <? } ?>
          <a href="/category/view?id=<?= $cat->id?>">Детальніше..</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте в пустом PHP файле так:

```
[]->count();
```

и вы получите ту же ошибку:

> Call to a member function count() on array

---

Всё дело в том, что когда вы вызываете такие методы как: `all()`, `one()`, `count()`, [etc](//yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html); то вы делаете непосредственно запрос к БД, а в вашем случае вам нужно просто вернуть объект с подготовленным запросом. Иными словами уберите из `getCategoryimg()` вызов `all()`.

---

[Документация](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/output-pagination.md)

[Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-pagination.html)

Comment: Запрос такой, что без ->all не выдает то, что нужно. Как можно переделать запрос?

Comment: @Vlad, что значит «не выдает то, что нужно»? Вы `all()` там где нужно убрали?

Comment: http://c2n.me/3Ahc9k0 - вьюха с ->all , http://c2n.me/3AhcbDn - вьюха без ->all

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Нет, как-то идей вообще нет, кроме как запроса с all(). А вы  ?

Comment: Я уже указал вам где ошибка ... Идей здесь никаких вообще не должно быть: здесь должна быть логика действий; так как мы не придумываем, а реализуем. Вы же можете узнать почему не отображаются изображения (у вас же данные в БД) — это первое; второе — вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос «что значит "не выдает то, что нужно"». Изображения не основное что нам нужно, нам нужны правильные записи из БД ...

Comment: да, Вы правы, цикл foreach ничего не возвращает. Не могу вывести ничего. Даже не знаю теперь как хоть что-то вывести в представлении...

Comment: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/  Даже в документации я не нашел пример использования без all() или one()

Comment: @Vlad, я же в ответе [ссылку на документацию дал](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/output-pagination.md), где это и видно: `$query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);` ...

Comment: Спасибо, получилось